# Have user chat output to admin chat in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I'm very new to JavaScript and Socket.io, I'm trying to create a space for the admins and the regular users.

only catch is I want the regular users chat to output to the admin chat.

How could I go about doing something like this? I've read the get started part and I'm still a bit lost.

Comment: Your question not clear what do you mean "only catch is I want the regular users chat to output to the admin chat."?

Comment: When the regular users talk in their chatroom, I want those messages to display in the admin chatroom as well.

Comment: Is this web app?

Comment: Yes sir, html and jquery

Comment: The question is too broad, please check here how to improve your questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you control the chat server and the socket connections you can direct the user data anywhere you need it to go. As such the question is far too broad for anyone to be able to answer. If you are struggling to implement this, please add your code to the question so we can understand the context you're working in, and help you debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain User flow, This may help to solve your problem.

```
let adminSockets = []; // Here I'm considering multiple admin
let userSocketMap = {};
```

When user Login you want to connect socket to server with identical(admin) handshake

```
io.of('/').on('connect', socket => {
  let { isAdmin, userId } = socket.handshake.headers
  if(isAdmin) {
    adminSockets.push(socket)
  } else {
    userSocketMap[userId] = socket;
  }
});
```

While user send message to one another(User 1 send message to User 2)

```
socket.on('send', (data) => { 
  let fromUserId = socket.handshake.headers.userId // User 1
  let toUser = data.toUserId // User 2 ( This is the user to whom you want to send message)
  let message = data.message
  let toSocket = userSocketMap[toUser];
  toSocket.emit({form: fromUserId, message: message})
  adminSockets.forEach(adminSocket => {
    adminSocket.emit({form: fromUserId, to: toUser, message: message})
  });
})
```